# Does Glue use S3 or HDFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I store my files in S3 and process them using AWS Glue. Glue in a serverless technology, and it spins up a Hadoop cluster in the background which you don't have to manage.

When I process my dataset, which is in S3, does Glue load it into the HDFS of the cluster than it spun up? Or does it process everything directly on S3?

I'm wondering about this, because I want to know if I should properly partition my dataset in S3, if Glue downloads all of it into HDFS, then I can repartition it when I run my Glue job, but if it doesn't load it into HDFS, I guess I have to keep it partitioned.